# What flash video codec am I missing? How can I fix it?

Tags: flash-player

I have noticed that a fair chunk (~10%) of flash videos are not playing correctly on my machine.

Here's one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWVN0sedvPU

It's **only the 360p version** of this video which isn't working. It displays like this:
[image]

The other versions of the video show up fine:
[image]

I've seen it occasionally on other sites including some BBC iPlayer videos.

What am I missing and how can I fix it?

(Flash Player 11,0,1,152, Google Chrome, Windows 7)

Answer (score 1):

The Flash's video codecs aren't the same type of codecs you install on Windows, they are internal, you can't install them. This looks more like some glitch or incompatibility. For instance, what's your graphics card, are its drivers updated?